# How can I use HTML5 email input type with server-side .NET

Tags: asp.net, html, webforms

As I understand it, the `<input type=email>` element in HTML5 will render as a simple text field in browsers that do not support the tag. On other browsers it will render properly, like on the iPhone it will bring up the e-mail keyboard layout.

I’d like to use this in a project but my input fields are `<asp:TextBox>` controls. How can I use the HTML5 element but still access its data server-side like the rest of my fields?

Comment: i should note, adding a simple runat=server to the input element with type=email did not work

Comment: If you give it a name then can't you just accesslike any other field with its name?

Comment: Could be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3388160/iphone-email-keyboard-layout-with-asp-net-textbox

Answer (score 25):

There is an update for .NET framework 4 which allows you to specify the type attribute

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2468871.

See `feature 3` way down the page

> Feature 3
>
> New syntax lets you define a
>   TextBox control that is HTML5
>   compatible. For example, the following
>   code defines a TextBox control that is
>   HTML5 compatible:
>
> ```
> <asp:TextBox runat="server" type="some-HTML5-type" />
> ```

Comment: Installed this update on a Windows 2003 server and it did not fix the problem however the answer by Milox did work.

Answer (score 17):

you can try adding the attributes manually, like:

```
TextBox1.Attributes["type"] = "email"; 
TextBox1.Attributes["type"] = "url"; 
TextBox1.Attributes["type"] = "number";
```

Comment: Works with ASP.NET 3.5

Answer (score 5):

Sorry I'm a bit late to the party, though I think that others can benefit from what I did. I have a page which is HTML 5 though we still have .NET 3.5. We wanted to keep the .NET element, though have the type change to email. I've tried several methods (including Milox above) to no avail, though the one which worked for me was the following: I added a JavaScript property to the element itself inline (when I put it in a script tag it wouldn't pick up for some reason...)
Here is what your tag would look like if you use my changes:

> `<asp:TextBox runat="server" type="email" onfocus="this.type='email'"/>`

Eli

Comment: Great solution! Works also with type=number, handy for mobile web pages

Comment: Glad it worked for you as well - you're very welcome!

Answer (score 3):

Whether or not it is accessible as a server control, you should be able to access the `HttpRequest.Form` collection and retrieve the value. No matter what the browser does with the tag, it has to submit a string to the server.

Comment: in the watch, i only see the runat=server controls in request.form. so that makes me think that this form is NOT sending that field to the server - only the runat=server controls

Answer (score 2):

in your .aspx file add

```
<input type="text" required autofocus placeholder="Email Address"
class="txt-input txt-input-username" ID="myTextBox" runat="server"/>
```

in your Code Behind .cs

```
myTextBox.Attributes["type"] = "email";
```

This Worked For Me

Answer (score 0):

You need to create your own custom control and override the Render routines.  Feel free to use either the source code or DLLs