# WebForms is not including email input type in form during autopostback

Tags: asp.net, html, webforms

I have an `asp:TextBox` on a page:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="edEmail" runat="server" />
```

And the form is submitted with a normal `<asp:Button>` control:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="edEmail" runat="server" />
<asp:Button ID="bbOK" Text="Save User" runat="server" OnClick="bbOK_Click" />
```

These are rendered into the client as:

```
<input name="ctl00$MainContent$edEmail" id="ctl00_MainContent_edEmail"></input>
<input name="ctl00$MainContent$bbOK" id="ctl00_MainContent_bbOK"     
       type="submit" value="Save User"
       onclick='javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions("ctl00$MainContent$bbOK", "", true, "", "", false, false))' >
```

When the form is submitted through a regular `<asp:Button>` everything sends correctly. Reading html forms is painful, but the formatted request body is:

- `&ctl00%24MainContent%24edEmail = asdf%40here.net`
- `&ctl00%24MainContent%24bbOK = Save+User`

Excellent, the e-mail address is going to the server. Next we will change the `type` of the input box to the new `html5` **email** type. We do this after installing the appropriate update to the .NET 4 Framework:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="edEmail" type="email" runat="server" />
<asp:Button ID="bbOK" Text="Save User" runat="server" OnClick="bbOK_Click" />
```

And now we repeat the same procedure. The rendered HTML is:

```
<input type="email" name="ctl00$MainContent$edEmail" id="ctl00_MainContent_edEmail" >
<input name="ctl00$MainContent$bbOK" id="ctl00_MainContent_bbOK"
       type="submit" value="Save User" 
       onclick="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$MainContent$bbOK&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, false))" >
```

And when we submit the form, the e-mail address form input is present:

- `&ctl00%24MainContent%24edEmail = asdf%40here.net`
- `&ctl00%24MainContent%24bbOK = Save+User`

Excellent, the browser (both IE11 and Chrome 30-something) are submitting the contents of the form as expected.

Next we add something to the page that triggers an *"auto-postback"*, an `<asp:RadioGroup>`:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="edEmail" type="email" runat="server" />

<asp:RadioButtonList ID="rbAccountType" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="rbAccountType_IndexChanged">
    <asp:ListItem>Windows</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Selected="True">Local</asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
<asp:Button ID="bbOK" Text="Save User" runat="server" OnClick="bbOK_Click" />
```

This gives the rendered HTML of:

```
<input type="email" name="ctl00$MainContent$edEmail" id="ctl00_MainContent_edEmail" >

<input id="ctl00_MainContent_rbAccountType_0" type="radio" name="ctl00$MainContent$rbAccountType" value="Windows" checked="checked"><label for="ctl00_MainContent_rbAccountType_0">Windows</label>
<input id="ctl00_MainContent_rbAccountType_1" type="radio" name="ctl00$MainContent$rbAccountType" value="Local" 
       onclick="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ctl00$MainContent$rbAccountType$1\',\'\')', 0)">    

<input name="ctl00$MainContent$bbOK" id="ctl00_MainContent_bbOK"
       type="submit" value="Save User" 
       onclick="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$MainContent$bbOK&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, false))" >
```

But when this form *"auto-postsback"*, the **email** field is missing:

- `&ctl00%24MainContent%24rbAccountType = Local&__ASYNCPOST=true&`

If i change the **email** input's `type` from `email` to `text`:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="edEmail" runat="server" Type="text" />
```

the rendered radiobutton remains unaffected:

```
<input id="ctl00_MainContent_rbAccountType_1" type="radio" name="ctl00$MainContent$rbAccountType" value="Local" 
       onclick="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ctl00$MainContent$rbAccountType$1\',\'\')', 0)">
```

but the postback data now (correctly) contains exactly what it's supposed to:

- `&ctl00%24MainContent%24edUsername = ian`
- `&ctl00%24MainContent%24edFullname = Ian%20Boyd`
- `&ctl00%24MainContent%24edDescription = foo`
- `&ctl00%24MainContent%24edEmail = asdf%40here.net`
- `&ctl00%24MainContent%24rbAccountType = Local&__ASYNCPOST=true&`

If i change it back to `email`:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="edEmail" runat="server" Type="email" />
```

it again fails, failing to include the `email` input type

- `&ctl00%24MainContent%24edUsername = ian`
- `&ctl00%24MainContent%24edFullname = Ian%20Boyd`
- `&ctl00%24MainContent%24edDescription = foo`
- `&ctl00%24MainContent%24rbAccountType = Local&__ASYNCPOST=true&`

## tldr

WebForms <strike>is a buggy architecture that i should have stopped using five years ago There's no fix, and Microsoft won't, so i'm just looking for commiserating.</strike> doesn't support HTML 5.

What is WebForms doing that uses the **browser** to not submit all fields in a form? The failure happens in the IE and Chrome client.

## Addendum

The title of this question calls out `email` input type. But the same bug happens for `number` input type; and presumably all html5 input types.

And marking up hyper-text in code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   edEmail.Attributes["type"] = "email";
   edEmployeeID.Attributes["type"] = "number";

   ...
}
```

does not solve it. The form still fails to submit its contained values during an *"auto-postback"* submit (and correctly submitting all values during a "regular" submit).

Impressive that 27 minutes after asking the question, Googling for:

> asp.net autopostback not including html5 input types

only gives me as the person experiencing the problem. Apparently i'm the only person trying to shoe-horn HTML5 into WebForms.

Comment: The "update" you mentioned, was it the [Reliability Update 1 for the .NET Framework 4](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2533523)?

Comment: This is a very well asked question with all the necessary details. Thanks for taking the time to write it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the bug in the generated WebForms client side Javascript code:

**ScriptResource.axd**

```
// Name:        MicrosoftAjaxWebForms.debug.js
// Assembly:    AjaxControlToolkit
// Version:     3.5.50401.0
// FileVersion: 3.5.50401
// (c) 2010 CodePlex Foundation
_onFormSubmit: function PageRequestManager$_onFormSubmit(evt)
{
   var count = form.elements.length;

   for (i = 0; i < count; i++) 
   {
       var element = form.elements[i];

       var tagName = element.tagName.toUpperCase();

       if (tagName === 'INPUT') 
       {
          var type = element.type;
          if ((type === 'text') ||
                (type === 'password') ||
                (type === 'hidden') ||
                (((type === 'checkbox') || (type === 'radio')) && element.checked)) 
          {
             formBody.append(encodeURIComponent(name));
             formBody.append('=');
             formBody.append(encodeURIComponent(element.value));
             formBody.append('&');
          }
       }
   }
}
```

By definition, WebForms will not input HTML5 input types in the form body during a postback. It will by definition only support the few original input types:

- `text`
- `password`
- `hidden`
- `checkbox`
- `radio`
- `color`  *unsupported*
- `date`  *unsupported*
- `datetime`  *unsupported*
- `datetime-local`  *unsupported*
- `email`  *unsupported*
- `month`  *unsupported*
- `number`  *unsupported*
- `range`  *unsupported*
- `search`  *unsupported*
- `tel`  *unsupported*
- `time`  *unsupported*
- `url`  *unsupported*
- `week`  *unsupported*

Comment: Interesting to know :)

Comment: You should mark this as the answer to your own question because it is. As a side note: the problem appears only on AJAX requests, not normal postbacks.

Answer (score 1):

You supposedly need to leave your server control as an `<asp:TextBox ... />` but override its `type` attribute in your code-behind:

```
edEmail.Attributes["type"] = "email";
```

<sub>[[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10802659/74757)]</sub>

Comment: Tested; does not work. The control renders with the appropriate `type`, but the auto-postback form does not contain form values.

Comment: Interesting. It certainly sounds like a bug. Are you using an `UpdatePanel` on your page?