# WebForms: Cannot find html input runat=server item from code behind

Tags: c#, webforms

I have an `input` with the `runat="server"` attribute set:

```
<div class="report-heading">
    <h2>Time Report</h2>
    <input type="date" id="dtbRunOnDate" runat="server" />
</div>
```

And use it in the code behind:

```
    if(!IsPostBack)
    {
        if (dtbRunOnDate.Value != "")
        {
            dtbRunOnDate.Value = DateTime.Today.ToString("mm/dd/yyyy");
        }
    }
```

Yet the compiler is saying it cannot be referenced in the code behind:

```
Error   CS0103  The name 'dtbRunOnDate' does not exist in the current context
```

Is this because I'm using an ASP.NET website instead of a web application?  I'm at a loss as to what to do here.

Comment: Interesting does  <input id="TEST" type="submit" runat=server /> have the same effect?

Also what does <asp:TextBox ID="Test" runat="server" > </asp:TextBox> do?

Comment: Check the designer if the id is created there , if not add manually

Comment: Could be the same issue that was in this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25024370/1429080). See also this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25025131/1429080) to the same question.

Comment: Is your input in any child controls like a `<asp:Repeater>` ?

Comment: Is your code-behind class inheriting the right page?