# Publishing ASP.Net website - email is not a valid type for an input tag

Tags: asp.net, html

I am trying to publish a website, but the compilation is failing with this error :

> email is not a valid type for an input tag

The markup is this

```
<input type="email" class="form-control" id="txtEmail" placeholder="Enter email" runat="server" />
```

It is running locally on my computer.

I have specified the Target Framework as this in the web.config (System.Web)

```
 <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5"/>
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
```

The error is preventing me from publishing unless I change the input type to text.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to decalre the type in code behind and see if it still gives you the same issue

Comment: Since .NET 4 should work with the TextBox control:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3232079/how-can-i-use-html5-email-input-type-with-server-side-net

Comment: Thanks Jurgen, Using the link supplied, txtEmail.Attributes.Add(["type"],"email"); in the code behind worked,

Answer (score -1):

```
  <asp:TextBox ID="txtvemail" CssClass="form-control" runat="server" placeholder="Type Email" </asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: Could you try to extend this at least a bit? Right now this appears to be too brief to be useful.